# how Hub Sites can be created/configured on SharePoint Online without using PowerShell. need to do it by online admin console

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

how Hub Sites can be created/configured on SharePoint Online without using PowerShell. I am looking for a way to configure my existing Team/Communications sites using the online admin console and not powershell.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Hub sites from the modern SharePoint Admin console by going to:

Sites-> Active Sites -> Select a site -> Hub site options

[image]